# Routing to a component with the default values

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React application I had implemented routing. 
In login component -> Accepting Username and Password.
If valid -> bookticket component -> Two buttons in this page - Viewshows and BookTicks.
Viewshows will display movie details.
BookTicks will route to BookTicks component.

After clicking on Viewshows, am clicking on book ticket button, so it will route to accept some user info for booking.
So my problem is I want to go back to bookticket component where only those two default buttons should be there. The table and other details should not be there.

I tried with history object but this is displaying buttons and also the details which I had viewed earlier.

`this.props.history.push('/bookticket');`

If a tag is used, its getting into 404 error, because it is deployed in IIS.

Comment: please share your Route components, rendered from within your BrowserRouter. You may need to add the `exact` boolean prop to each Route that you want to appear by themselves

Comment: ```<BrowserRouter>
            <React.Fragment>
                <Layout component={LoginContainer} path= {"/"} exact />
        <Layout component={BookContainer} path={"/viewshows"} />
                <Layout component={ShowsContainer} path={"/bookticket"} />
            </React.Fragment>
        </BrowserRouter>```

Comment: so if your Layout Component is passing all props to an underlying Route Component, then you'll want to pass `exact` to all of your Layout Components here

Comment: I had added exact and deployed but no luck same problem.. When I route programmatically, should I include something else to get the component with initial stage or initial layout

Comment: In localhost, I was able to achieve using a tag. but in IIS it altogether different game

Comment: I'm not sure about IIS. I was referring to this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool for why you want to use exact on all routes to ensure only the particular route you are looking for is matched